# Trying to switch Py versions in Anaconda and within Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, switching

I know this might be a silly question but I need help going from 3.8 python in Spyder to 3.5. I found an old answer to the problem however, when i go through the steps is not working. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You could just create a new environment with python 3.5 installed